# How to curve my subdivided mesh along it's y axis

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a simple mesh that i have subdivided along its y-axis, i want to curve it along an arc but i can't find the way to do it with a modifier, how exactly can i curve it along an arc?

[image: mod]

Comment: Ah yes it does, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [curve modifier].

See a video tutorial on the famous video website or search here at BSE.

You can also use [Simple Deform] modifier.

You can also use proportional edit.

You can also use an armature modifier.